# How to stop the whole loop?

Tags: python

I have a problem in the loop below for python.

It doesn't stop as soon as totalout=4, but only when the whole loop for scorein is over. (i.e. the thrid loop)

For example, if the totalout=4 in scorein number 2, it runs the loop till it reaches 10

```
#global value   
totalturn=0
totalscorein=0
totalout=0

def main

  numberofturn=int(input("Number of score:"))

  no_turn=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'] 
    #while loop condition    
    while totalturn<numberofturn and totalout<10:

            #increasement
            totalscore+=1

            #for loop for score
            for t in range(1,numberofturn+1):
                turns=s*1

                print("\n\n\nThe turn"+no_turn[t]+":",turns)

                #for loop for number to appear from list
                for c in range (10):

                    #list for random number to appear
                    numscore = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','o']

                    #random choice from numscore list to appear
                    from random import choice
                    scorein=choice(numscore)

                    print ("\n\nScores :",scorein)




                    if scorein.isdigit():
                        totalscorein=totalscorein+int(scorein)               


                    if scorein.isalpha():
                        totalout+=1



                    if totalturn==numberofturn:
                        print("\nTotal turn played:",totalturn)


                    elif totalout==4:

                        print("\nTotal turns played",totalturn)
                        break

                    else:

                        print("")
```

Comment: what's the value of totalscore, numberofscore and totalout before the while loop?

Comment: `totalscore`, `numberofscore` are not declared and your first line should use an assignment rather than colon (plus `list` is not a good choice for a variable name).

Comment: sorry 
I have make changes already

Comment: you should post your actual code. There are a lot of mistakes here so this code can not even run

Comment: Is it because of the order of loops is wrong?

I am new to python... 

What I want to do is:
First the program run for turn1
then under turn 1, loop for 10 scores
then turn 2, loop for 10 scores and so on
if score is 'o' and totalouts=4, I want to stop the whole loop including the turn loop
but now I can only stop score loop only when it reaches to score number 10 but turn loop didn't stop

Comment: there are too many errors here: what is s?
totalscore+=1 please declare it first.

Comment: Sorry this one is just part of the code... and yes edited one... 
Now it's been solved.
Thanks for all the helps :)

Comment: I couldn't upload my actual code cos I am afraid of pilgrims
Next time, I will try to be more careful to upload a correct code
As I am very new to python or any other program language, it is really hard for me to write one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the `break` to break out of the 3 loops? I guess you are judging from the title of the question

In this case, since it is the end of the function, you could just replace `break` with `return`

Comment: Thanks alot
Yes I want to break out all 3loops
It's working!!
Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `and` operator to `or`. That seems to be what you want.

`while totalscore<numberofscore or totalout<10:`